# Android LocationManager encapsulation issue

Tags: android, encapsulation, locationmanager

I'm trying to call the requestLocationUpdates method but eclipse says that the arguments are wrong.

The Main activity is set as :

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements LocationListener{... }
```

and the code with errors is :

```
    final LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

    trackLocation.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

            boolean tracking = false;

            if (!tracking){
               locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);
            } else {
                // something
            }
        }
    });
```

The locationManager.... line works fine outside the onClickListener.

What should be the right parameter to fix?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace "this" with "MainActivity.this".

If you just have "this", you are passing in the OnClickListener instead of the Activity.